# I keep getting the error `Central Directory corrupt` when trying to use ZipArchive

Tags: c#, stream, c#-ziparchive

My code looks like below.

```
public async Task<MetaDataItem> GetMetadata(Stream sm){
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(sm, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true))
    {
        if (archive.Entries.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            MetaDataItem metaItem = new MetaDataItem();
            //process contents of archive
            return metaItem;
        }

    }
    return null;

}
```

```
public async Task<bool> ExtractData(Stream sm, string file){
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
    if (ext.ToLower().Equals(".zip"))
    {
        isZip = true;
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(sm, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true))
        {
            // Some processing on the entries here.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

```
var objectStream  = await cloudDataManager.DownloadPackage(dataKey);

using(objectStream){
    var metadata = await GetMetadata(objectStream); 
    var res = await ExtractData(objectStream, dataKey);
}
```

At the line `using (var archive = new ZipArchive(sm, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true))` in ExtractData I get the exception:

```
Central Directory corrupt.
[System.IO.IOException] = {"An attempt was made to move the position before the beginning of the stream."}
```

Note sure what is wrong here or how to fix it.

For some context, `cloudDataManager.DownloadPackage(dataKey)` downloads a zip file from could storage (S3) bucket. I can confirm that this function does not close (dispose) the stream that is returned.

Comment: Can you extract the zip content with Windows explorer? I mean, are you sure the zip is valid?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the direct solution to the problem here, but it might help someone getting the same error messages.

The error message I got was `IOException: Attempted to Seek before the beginning of the stream`. But in the callstack this `Rethrow as InvalidDataException: Central Directory corrupt.` was hidden, which revealed the problem for me.

In the end, the solution was to inspect the .zip archive using the file explorer. I had accidentally overwritten it using `File.Create` with the wrong path parameter.

Comment: I am facing same exception but not sure about the root cause.  Can you shed some light?

Comment: Which exception do you get? The "Central Directory corrupt" exception or the IOException? The root cause for me was a function that had overridden the .zip archive with the File.Create function, which resulted in a corrupt .zip archive.

Comment: I am getting "System.IO.InvalidDataException: Central Directory corrupt. ---> System.IO.IOException: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file."

Comment: Above exception is throw from "at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(string source, string destination)"